# How to reach to an PHP object array?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I have an object and contents are

```
Braintree_Result_Successful Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [_returnObjectName:private] => transaction
    [transaction] => Braintree_Transaction Object
        (
            [_attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => grmjyg
```

Let's say this varialbe is **$result**
I'm trying to reach **id** . I think I could reach it as

```
$result->transcation->_attributes['id']
```

But I get an error. How can I reach to it?

Comment: Try spelling transaction correctly?

Comment: @animuson Thanks so much. I should have a rest I think :) Sorry for taking your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try spelling it correctly :)

```
$result->transaction->_attributes['id']
```